# how to draw the following text inside a rectangle in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[blue!20!black,fill=blue!20,rounded corners=10,thick] (0,0) rectangle (3,1) node {text};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would like to have the word "text" centered inside the node. I tried all sort of options, and it didn't work.

In addition, I would like to draw an identical node on the right of this one, and have an arrow between the two.

Comment: It's because you did not search `node` in PGF manual % PGF manual https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf
`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[cc/.style={draw=blue,fill=blue!20,rounded corners=2pt,thick}]
\path 
(0,0) node[cc] (A) {first text}
(3,0) node[cc] (B) {first text}
;
\draw[->] (A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 4):

Instead of drawing the shapes and then placing a node in the center, you can give the node the shape you want and then place the node where you want. Since you want the same node repeated, you can define a `style` using `tikzset` that can be used in multiple tikzpictures.

```
\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw=blue!20!black, fill=blue!20, rounded corners=10, thick, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm}}
```

Then you can place the nodes manually if you want by specifying their coordinates.

[image]

But here are two other possibilities for placement.

Using `positioning`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw=blue!20!black, fill=blue!20, rounded corners=10, thick, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=10mm]
\node[mynode](A){Text 1};
\node[mynode, right=of A](B){Text 2};
\node[mynode, right=of B](C){Text 3};
\draw[thick, ->](A)--(B);
\draw[thick, ->](B)--(C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Using `chains`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw=blue!20!black, fill=blue!20, rounded corners=10, thick, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain, node distance=10mm, every join/.style={->, thick}]
\node[on chain, mynode](A){Text 1};
\node[on chain=going right, mynode, join](B){Text 2};
\node[on chain=going right, mynode, join](C){Text 3};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Manual placement (slightly different spacing because this places the node centers and doesn't account for the thickness of the node borders):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={draw=blue!20!black, fill=blue!20, rounded corners=10, thick, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[mynode] at (0,0) (A){Text 1};
\node[mynode] at (4,0) (B){Text 2};
\node[mynode] at (8,0) (C){Text 3};
\draw[thick, ->](A)--(B);
\draw[thick, ->](B)--(C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \draw[blue!20!black,fill=blue!20,rounded corners=10,thick] (0,0) rectangle (3,1) node[midway] {text};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```